# How do I change the css of only one page in wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress

I need to change the css of the home page only, I have googled and a lot of the suggestions were to add the page id as part of the css selector. But when I try it, it doesn't seem to work? I want to change the class ".contentclass" and the pages id is "599" so here's what I've tried:

```
.post-id-599 .contentclass {}
.page-id-599 .contentclass {}
.body-id-599 .contentclass {}
```

none of them seems to be working...

Link to the webpage I'm working on: [Link](http://witdesign.se/wp/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your theme uses [body_class()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class) in the body tag, you will have a specific css class for the front page (`.home`), which you could use in the stylesheet;

Example (might be different for your theme):

`.home #content .entry { color: #123edf; }`

to overwerite the genral stylesheet style.css, you could use a conditional statement in header.php to link a specific stylesheet for the front page:

Example:

```
<?php if( is_home() ) { ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/front-style.css" />
<?php } ?>
```

the code needs to be after the link to the general stylesheet.

(instead of `is_home()` you might need to use `is_front_page()` )

Check: [Conditional_Tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) and [get_stylesheet_directory_uri](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri)

--
alternative, to load a different stylesheet instead of the general stylesheet, use the conditional statement with an `else`:
(this code would replace the link of the general stylesheet)

Example:

```
<?php if( is_home() ) { ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/front-style.css" />
<?php } else { ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' ); ?>" />
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I'd suggest using `body.home` in your CSS file instead of `.home` just in case the theme author has used a `home` class anywhere else.

Comment: Awesome! I tried with the body.home and it worked exceptionally, thank you so much! @Chankey Pathak

Answer (score 7):

Try using the right click "inspect element" or equivalent for your browser.

When I look at your site I see something like this

[image]

```
<body class="page page-id-624 woocommerce-cart woocommerce-page boxed varukorg" style="">
```

So for example for this page:
http://witdesign.se/wp/varukorg
you would use

```
body.post-id-624 .contentclass {}
```

Any styles within the braces will be applicable to the pages with a body class of post-id-668

To be sure, you will need to check what renders in your browser using an inspector.

Comment: That worked for me. Thanks. First time I learn an easy way to apply CSS for only one page.  I didn't use <body>.