# Wordpress - Hide elements based on post_id

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I would like to create a function that will hide an element from sidebar based on post id.
Can I write if post-in function that will activate on page load in js or I need to find the function that creates sidebar and change it there? I would love to see sample code for js (I am still new to js), but all the code I find online is for CSS only.

Comment: Hiding elements sounds exactly like a job for CSS, not JS. So why would you want to do it in JS? Besides that, many themes (like the default WP themes) add a class `.post-120` (where 120 is the post id) or even an id `#post-120` to some element in the DOM. That would be a way to get that information via JS.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63440874/3825777 https://stackoverflow.com/a/23363654/3825777